# JSON to YAML in Python : How to get correct string manipulation?

Tags: python, json, yaml

I'm using the [PyYAML library](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) to convert json to yaml. But quotation marks are removed from string values when they should not be. They should only be removed from keys.

I have used the default_flow_style option with the yaml dump function as illustrated below :

```py
import yaml

x = {'name':'Alice','location':'New York', 'profession':'coder'}
yaml.dump(x, default_flow_style=False)
```

The actual result is :
`'location: New York\nname: Alice\nprofession: coder\n'`

When the desired result is :
`"location: 'New York'\nname: 'Alice'\nprofession: 'coder'\n"`

Comment: They are equivalent from YAML's point of view. Quotation marks are mostly optional.

Comment: In that sense the whole conversion is optional since YAML is a superset of JSON.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know they were considered equivalent and that YAML is a superset of JSON.

Comment: @LeoE YAML has been a superset of JSON for all intents and purposes since version 1.2 released in 2009, but the (outdated) PyYAML library you are using only supports YAML 1.1.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon ... That's where I may have gotten confused.  I do not know why it is considered to be the standard yaml library for python even though outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyYAML library that you are using doesn't readily give you that
kind of control. It drops the original quotation if superfluous when you
load-then-dump YAML (version 1.1) with it. And if you specify
`default_style='"'` **every** string gets quoted, including keys.

`ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) can do this
kind of round-tripping while allowing you to retain your specific and/or
superfluous quotes. Its mechanism to do so, provides you with types
that you can use out of the box.

Thanks to 
[David Fraser](https://bitbucket.org/davidfraser/pyyaml/commits/d81df6eb95f20cac4a79eed95ae553b5c6f77b8c)
you can also easily have non-quoted mapping keys, while all the rest is double quoted:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


def non_quoted_key(self, data):
   if isinstance(data, ruamel.yaml.compat.string_types):
       data = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PlainScalarString(data)
   return self.represent_data(data)

x = {'name':'Alice', 'location':'New York', 'profession':'coder'}
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.default_style = '"'
yaml.Representer.represent_key = non_quoted_key
yaml.dump(x, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
name: "Alice"
location: "New York"
profession: "coder"
```

Comment: Thanks for your post!  It addresses the issue (in cases where you really need quotation marks).  It is fine if you are the package author.  In fact, your package should be the standard python yaml library rather than PyYAML.